# How to connect to a OPC-UA server from PHP?

Tags: php, python, c++, opc-ua

OPC-UA gains traction in smart manufaturing. I need to connect to a OPC-UA server from PHP. Since I could not find an open sourced native PHP client, there are several ways I am thinking about:

- writing a native client in PHP from scratch
- wrapping a C/C++ library in PHP
- calling an UPC-UA commandline executable client using exec()
- transfering a C/C++ , JAVA or Python OPC-UA client to PHP line-by-line

Are there other ways to go?

Is anybody working on an open source implementation in PHP?

How to proceed? What would be your choice? And how do you expect the caveats and efforts for these variants?

Comment: have u got anything on this?

Comment: @AjitSingh: no, currently working with microservices (Docker) and using a seperate container with node-opcue library. works, but a pure PHP solution still would be better.

Comment: im also doing the same thing. but not with docker. can u help me or share some light how u are doing it.

Comment: Any chance you could post your node-opcua/php solution?

Comment: @VoteCoffee Sorry no. Currently we are using two methods to access OPC/UA servers from PHP: 1) a Docker container with NodeJS and superb http://node-opcua.github.io library with an Express-http server and MQTT broker for access from PHP and 2) Node-RED with OPC/UA node as intermediate and builtin MQTT/http for PHP access. Depending on your requirements and skill, Node-RED is a good starting point